# How do graphing applications calculate viewing area?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, graph

I am working on an application that displays a scatterplot of data but I am wondering what the "rule of thumb" is that graphing applications use to calculate the Y-axis maximum and minimum viewing area values.  For example, in the graph below, the chart displays values from ~40 minutes to ~100 minutes.  It looks like it is just determining the maximum/minimum points displayed and then adding some small margin.

Is there a good whitepaper or calculation that is frequently used to calculate the viewing area?

[image]

Image linked from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot) page on scatter plots.

Comment: No, unless you count "whatever looks nice".

Comment: So what "looks nice"?  I presume this will change depending on the data.  The issue I would like to get away from is having to tweak this several several times by having the hive mind give me some pointers.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at some of the many excellent available books on _data visualization_. Good starts would be the books from Edward Tufte, Nathan Yau, and Julie Steele.

Comment: You are in the wrong site then - this is about *aesthetics*, not coding. Different screen sizes look good with different margins. Different *shapes* also look nice with different margins (square, wide, tall ?). Small paintings have wide frames while large paintings have narrow frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly believe each graphing library uses its own "visual guidelines" (that might very well be undocumented) to determine a larger or a smaller "margin" around data.

A good formula to calculate viewing area from data range (considering only Y axis) would be, in pseudocode:

```
var margin = 0.1; (ten percent of data range)
var ymin = data.min();
var ymax = data.max();
var data_range = abs(ymax - ymin);
var y_plot_min = ymin - data_range * margin;
var y_plot_max = ymax + data_range * margin;
set_plot_y_limits(y_plot_min, y_plot_max);
```

Comment: In short - 10% all around. That will look a bit empty for large sizes. You just can't calculate aesthetics

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you could have a margin in graph space (pixels) instead of data space, if desired. It all comes down to preference in the end, and you can get better and better results the more you are able to model and represent your aesthetic preferences mathematically, IMO. Of course, more complex preferences and heuristics will require more complex calculation models.